# How to check whether the email is in valid format or not?

Tags: ios, email-validation

I am using the following code to check the validation of my email which is entered in the uitextfield. But it is returning true when I enter abcd@m.com.com it is not returning false.

```
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
```

Anyone can suggest me ?

Comment: There are many discussions about using regular expressions for validating email addresses, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address. - Also `abcd@m.com.com` looks "well-formed" to me (but I may be wrong!) and matches the regular expression. Why do you expect to get false?

Comment: `abcd@m.com.com` can be a valid email address!

Comment: But I don't need the abcd@m.com.com. I need like abcd@m.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't exclude the domain `m.com.com`, as it's a possible subdomain of `com.com` (wich maybe looks strange, but is a valid - and btw. real - domain).

If you still want to exclude all subdomains (saying: only allow one `.` after `@`) you would exclude email addresses like:

- **example@provider.co.uk**
- example@groups.google.com
- example@press.apple.com
- example@support.stackexchange.com
- abcd@m.com.com

So, you maybe don't want to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

Email validation for ios code.

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)email
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

**Textfield delegate**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if ([self validateEmailWithString:textField.text])
    {
        Nslog(@"Valid");
    }
    else
    {
        Nslog(@"Not Valid");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using the same code. I don't want another .com  in the email address and should return as false. I need like ancd@m.com

Comment: Why do you want to exclude .com.com?

Comment: *m.com.com* is a (possible) subdomain of com.com